# how to load SharePoint default .js file manually in master page?

Tags: custom-masterpage, sharepoint-calendar, debugging, apple-ios, sp.ui

I have created SharePoint calendar list and added it to my custom page (with the custom master page).some time **sp.ui.applicationpages.calendar.debug.js** not loaded in IOS mobiles(also not loaded in system pages).
how to load this files manually in the master page.
suggest some idea to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to include this in the masterpage where the script links are located.

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="SPCalendarDebug" name="sp.ui.applicationpages.calendar.debug.js" runat="server" ondemand="false" localizable="false" loadafterui="true" />
```